# Power BI trigger snowflake procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to call a procedure from snowflake from within power bi when the datamodel is refreshed. The procedure itself is just an insert from one table to another table.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing? Is the issue that you don't know how to call an SP from PowerBI, or are you stuck on how to trigger it as part of the refresh - or something else?

Comment: Hi, sorry, just realised that the message posted was pretty unclear. Yes, trying to have a store procedure triggered on pbi refresh